# How to get control of Windows of WindowXP using Java

Tags: java, dll, native, jna

I need to get control over Windows of WindowsXP using Java code,
I need to click/type on particular button/textfield of given window of windowsXP,
How to do this any idea?

Approaches I tried are:
(1) I Tried AutoIT framework, but its Java Wrapper is buggy.. not stable.

(2) JNA can be used for native interfacing, by using some .dll file
to achieve the same. But I don't know which .dll file is used by windowsXP.

Can anybody elaborate on this?

I've not much idea which is much better solution.
Is there any better framework available for such thing.

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do??

Comment: @Neal: I need to simulate some action on WindowsXP system, like if want to open notepad, write something, click file menu, save file etc...

Comment: cant the user do that themselves?

Comment: Why do you need to start Notepad to create a text file?

Answer (score 0):

WindowsXP uses multiple dll files, not one, and studying its API will tell you which one has which functions, and then you can use this information in  your JNA interaction code. BTW, I have use AutoIt by itself to help do what you're trying to do and it works fine, and is easier than Java with JNA since it's built for this sort of thing. I've also used AutoIt with Java by having Java call small AutoIt programs and get some simple interaction via standard input and output streams taking care though of the tips and traps in this great article: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: Thanks but AutoIt is not working when RDP is closed. Or do you have any work around to make AutoITscript work on closed RDP?

Comment: @SmartSolution: By RDP, I assume you mean *Remote Desktop Protocol*.  Can you give us more specifics of your problem?  Also, have you looked here? [AutoIT running in RDP sessions](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/127212-autoit-running-in-rdp-sessions/page__p__890346__hl__rdp__fromsearch__1#entry890346)